# Уведомление не отличается от цитат

Tags: предложение, дефект, статус-отложено

Внёс [предлагаемую правку](//rus.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29710) в [вопрос](//rus.stackexchange.com/q/454309/185185) и получил уведомление о том, что она ожидает проверки. Проблема в том, что оно выглядит в точности так же, как обычная цитата:

> [image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо за сообщение!

Сообщение о проблеме передано разработчикам.

Пост на MSE: [Vagueness in the quote and notification bars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332702/379531).